# 'No module named spacy' in ipython, but works fine in regular python interpretter

Tags: python, path, nlp, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

I am currently trying to import spacy using Jupyter Notebooks and running into a problem. Every time I try to import it, it says that it cannot find the module, even though the regular python shell interpreter works just fine.

Information:

- Conda Environment
- installed using conda install -c conda-forge spacy
- shows up in conda list | grep spacy
- Jupyter can find other packages in the conda env, just not spacy

Thank you for any help you can provide.

EDIT: Terminal Commands:

`1. cd into project directory
2. conda create -n <env name>
3. source activate <env name>
4. conda install -c conda-forge spacy
5. python -m spacy download en
6. python
- import spacy            #works!
- nlp = spacy.load('en')  #works!
- quit()
7. ipython
- import spacy
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'spacy'`

EDIT2:
Figured it out. My sys.path was different in ipython and wasn't searching through the conda env. I had to run conda install jupyter in the env and then everything worked. Apparently the root jupyter doesn't detect if you're inside an environment or not.

Comment: could you share with us commands you ran on your terminal, it will be much easier

Comment: @Carole edited the original post. Hopefully this helps. Let me know if you need further clarification. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

Figured it out. My sys.path was different in ipython v python shell. ipython wasn't searching through the conda env.

I had to run conda install jupyter in the env and then everything worked. Apparently the root jupyter doesn't detect if you're inside an environment or not. This makes sense now that I know some more about the internals as it needs to identify with a specific ipykernel.

Hope this helps anyone else running into the same issue.

Comment: for future similar issue, check here : https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2017/12/05/installing-python-packages-from-jupyter/

Answer (score 3):

- create virtualenv
- activate it
- install jupyter and spacy on virtualenv

> ```
> pip install jupyter     
> pip install spacy
> ```

- add kernel

> ```
> pip install ipykernel
> python -m ipykernel install --user --name=newkernelinvenv
> ```

start jupyter and load your new kernel

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue when I installed Spacy in Windows. I just had to run my command window as administrator. 
Sometimes we make stupid mistakes :)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative without installing Jupyter inside your venv is:

```
$ python -m venv projectname
$ source projectname/bin/activate
(venv) $ pip install ipykernel
(venv) $ ipython kernel install --user --name=projectname
(venv) $ conda install -c conda-forge spacy
(venv) $ jupyter notebook
```

Credits: https://anbasile.github.io/programming/2017/06/25/jupyter-venv/